# specifying the TiKV cluster endpoint as the backing data store error

Tags: tikv, surrealdb

1.start tikv commang:

```
#  tiup playground --tag surrealdb --mode tikv-slim --pd 1 --kv 1
tiup is checking updates for component playground ...
Starting component `playground`: /root/.tiup/components/playground/v1.11.0/tiup-playground --tag surrealdb --mode tikv-slim --pd 1 --kv 1
Using the version v6.2.0 for version constraint "".

If you'd like to use a TiDB version other than v6.2.0, cancel and retry with the following arguments:
    Specify version manually:   tiup playground <version>
    Specify version range:      tiup playground ^5
    The nightly version:        tiup playground nightly
    Playground Bootstrapping...
    Start pd instance:v6.2.0
    Start tikv instance:v6.2.0
    PD client endpoints: [127.0.0.1:2379]
    To view the Prometheus: http://127.0.0.1:9090
    To view the Grafana: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

2.start surrealdb,specifying the TiKV cluster endpoint as the backing data store.

```
[2022-09-25 04:12:10] INFO  surrealdb::iam Root authentication is enabled
[2022-09-25 04:12:21] INFO  surrealdb::iam Root username is 'root'
[2022-09-25 04:12:26] INFO  surrealdb::dbs Database strict mode is disabled
[2022-09-25 04:12:32] INFO  surrealdb::kvs Connecting to kvs store at tikv://127.0.0.1:2379
[2022-09-25 04:13:32] INFO  surrealdb::kvs Connected to kvs store at tikv://127.0.0.1:2379
[2022-09-25 04:13:36] ERROR surrealdb::cli There was a problem with the database: There was a problem with the underlying datastore: [/home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-client-pd-0.1.0/src/cluster.rs:174]: PD cluster failed to respond
```

prompt error：“ERROR surrealdb::cli There was a problem with the database: There was a problem with the underlying datastore: [/home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-client-pd-0.1.0/src/cluster.rs:174]: PD cluster failed to respond”。

Comment: https://github.com/surrealdb/docker.surrealdb.com/issues/3

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact problem on my M1 Mac Mini. Here are the steps I took to solve it.

1. Reinstall Surreal DB:
   brew reinstall surreal
2. Reboot:
   Just in case...
3. Open a terminal window and start tiup:
   tiup playground --tag surrealdb --mode tikv-slim --pd 1 --kv 1
4. Open another terminal window and start SurrealDB:
   surreal start --log debug --user root --pass root memory

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://github.com/surrealdb/docker.surrealdb.com/issues/3